# Reference for spherical distance

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

[Here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalDistance.html) we can find a formula for a distance on the sphere $\Bbb S^n=\{(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\;:\;x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n+1}^2=1\}\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

The one point compactification of $\Bbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb S^n$ via stereographic projection:
\begin{align*}
\varphi_n&\colon\overline{\Bbb R^n}\to\Bbb S^n\\
\varphi_n(x)&=\frac2{\|x\|^2+1}\left(x,\frac{\|x\|^2-1}{2}\right),\;\;x\neq\infty\\
\varphi_n(\infty)&=(0,\dots,0,1)
\end{align*}
This allows us to define a notion of distance on any such $\overline{\Bbb R^n}$ as
$$
d_n(x,y):=\arccos(\varphi_n(x)\cdot\varphi_n(y)),\;\;\;x,y\in\overline{\Bbb R^n}\;\;,
$$
where $\cdot$ denotes the scalar product in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

I need to quote this result, so can somebody tell me a book in which I can find it?

Comment: A useful search phrase is [chordal metric](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chordal+metric%22+n-dimensional&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 0):

Brannan, D. A, Matthew F Esplen, and Jeremy Gray. 1999. Geometry. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.  and the proof and explanations are on p.144